# Using Splunk to identify relatively unusual categorical event

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I am starting off with Splunk and trying to solve a problem. I have a data set with millions of log records. The use case is to identify events that are unusual for a specific role and highlight the event and the user. The below table gives a snapshot of the data. The task is to append the last two columns and for each role, identify the appended events that has happened relatively lower than other appended events in the same role.

```
 user_name  role         event_name     event_type
    A1     Provider     Open Session    Patient
    A1     Provider     Open Session    Patient
    A1     Provider     View Session    Patient
    B1     Provider     Search Session  Admin
    B1     Provider     Search Session  Admin
    B1     Provider     Search Session  Patient
    B1     Provider     Search Session  Admin
    B1     Provider     Open Session    Admin
    C1     Physician    Open Session    Patient
    C1     Physician    Modify Session  Patient
    C1     Physician    Modify Session  Patient
    C2     Physician    Open Session    Patient
    C2     Physician    Open Session    Patient
    C3     Physician    Modify Session  Admin
```

If I want to find unusual events for the role "Provider" the output should be

```
    user_name    role        appended_event     
        A1     Provider     View Session Patient    
        B1     Provider     Search Session Patient
        B1     Provider     Open Session Admin
```

Similarly, if I want to find the unusual events for the role "Physician" the output should be

```
    user_name    role        appended_event     
        C3     Physician        Modify Session Admin
```

I am also looking for a way to visualize such a report.
Any help on this would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this and then define your own thresholds:

```
| eventstats count as role_event_count by role appended_event
| eventstats count as role_count by role 
| eval pct = role_event_count / role_count * 100
```